# Python script issue posting JSON to ACF to REST API

Tags: python, wordpress, api, advanced-custom-fields

I’m having hard time figuring why I’m getting back this error after making a POST:

```
{"code":"cant_update_item","message":"Cannot update item","data":{"status":500}}
```

the data that I’m posting is this one:

```
post = { 'allega_file' : { '_file' : [232] } }
```

where ‘allega_file’ is an ACF that contains a repeater field ‘_file’ where the id of the file is attached.

I thought was an Authorization error but, after producing one of those I saw that the feedback it’s completely different.
I took the reference on how structuring the repeater JSON from this POST
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-update-acfs-using-json/

Do you guys know where I’m doing it wrong?
Here you can find the python script I'm using to test the ACF to REST API
based on this example https://discussion.dreamhost.com/t/how-to-post-content-to-wordpress-using-python-and-rest-api/65166 (that works great for Posting articles, and media).

```
import requests
import json

user = 'user'
pythonapp = 'mykey'
url = 'http://www.example.coop/wp-json/acf/v2/page/149'

headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'base64user:pythonapp'}
post = { 'allega_file' : { '_file' : [232] } }                      
r = requests.post(url + '/posts', headers=headers, json=post)

print(headers) #just to check
print(url) #just to check

print(str(r.content))
```

To authenticate the script into WP I'm using this plugin
https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords/

The ACF to REST API plugin instead is this one:
https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api

Comment: Generally `50X` statuses means internal server errors, and not a client error (usually `40X`) - it maybe that the service is not functioning correctly and there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I thought it, could it be maybe the auth plugin that isn't working correctly with the ACF to REST API plugin.  It works great instead with single posts and media. Do you have experience with that plugin?

Comment: No I don't, but if you have access to the server check out the server logs for any failures.

Comment: Done it. It's pretty funny. Fron access.log I can see my attempt to reach the API endpoint and it shows the relative 500 error but I can't find the error in the error.log. Apparently, there aren't any error after 7th of June

Comment: After receiving a feedback from the developer of the Plugin I've edited my code following his suggestion to edit the data structure (include a 'fields' key before 'allega_file') but unfortunately I'm having the same issue. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/python-script-fails-posting-some-data/